# Issues with leipzig and glossaries used together

Tags: glossaries, incompatibility, linguistics, leipzig

I am preparing a document containing some interlinear glossing, the glossing conventions themselves appearing as a separate list. I use the [leipzig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leipzig) package to typeset the glosses, the [expex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) package to format numbered examples and the [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package to create the list of abbreviations.

MWE#1 gets the shape of the glosses right, both inside a numbered example and outside: there is no spacing between the 1, the SG, the colon and the DAT in the pdf output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl
\gla mulle //
\glb \First\Sg:\Dat{} //
\endgl
\xe

go.\Pst{}

\end{document}
```

However, if I load the [glossaries](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package in line with the instructions in the [leipzig](http://ctan.org/pkg/leipzig) manual, as shown in MWE#2, I get unwanted spacing on either side of the SG bit. Besides, inline glosses appear in the output unfolded into *go*.PSTpastpst as opposed to the desired *go*.PST

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\usepackage[nomain,nostyles]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl
\gla mulle//
\glb \First\Sg:\Dat{}//
\endgl
\xe

go.\Pst{}

\printglossary[style=inline,type=\leipzigtype]

\end{document}
```

Is there a way of rectifying this? I'm compiling these particular MWEs with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) but have tried both Xe- and LuaLaTeX as well, both times with the same result.

Comment: leipzig 2.0 is now available on CTAN (2017-06-16), and it fixes this issue (among others). However, if you are still using leipzig 1.0/1.1, then you can hack this by using `\glsunsetall` in your preamble. 

The reason you see PSTpastpst is a combination of bugs, but mostly because leipzig thinks you want the full abbreviation printed, as if on first use. Using `\glsunsetall` unsets the first use flag that is used by glossaries.

(Sorry, I don't know why the extra spaces were showing up! Perhaps the above hack will fix that too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't replicate the spacing issue around the SG, so this answer might not help you with that.

The *go*.PSTpastpst issue is related to the usage of the obsolete `glossaries` commands `\defglsdisplay` and `\defglsdisplayfirst` in `leipzig.sty`.

Here is what is in v1.0 of `leipzig.sty` on line 128:

```
\newcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}[1]{%
    \defglsdisplay[#1]{\leipzigfont{##1}##4}%
    \defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{\firstleipzigfont{##1}##4}%
}
```

You should create a copy of `leipzig.sty`, save it with a new name, and then change the above lines to the following. You will then need to load the modified style file instead of `leipzig.sty`.

```
\newcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}%
}
```

This gets rid of the obsolete command errors and also solves your *go*.PSTpastpst issue.

Comment: This doesn't work as advertised.

Comment: @egreg, can you elaborate? Are you saying that after modifying `leipzig.sty` as I suggested you still get the error that the OP mentions? Or do you mean that the fix works but has unintended consequences?

Comment: If I apply `\renewcommand...` in the file, instead of changing `leipzig.sty`, I don't seem to get the right result.

Comment: To understand more what egreg is talking about, you might want to look at the [follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230874/32888) that I asked. Also, trying to figure this out is the first time that I've ever looked at the `glossaries` package, so I have no idea what I'm doing, but according to the manual, `\defglsdisplay` and `\defglsdisplayfirst` were deprecated for `\defglsentryfmt`.

Comment: Anyway, the real answer is that this is a bug in `leipzig` and should be fixed since those commands were deprecated in `glossaries`. I've emailed Natalie about this, but I think she's writing her dissertation right now and might be preoccupied.

Comment: In addition to the manual, see also: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/featuretracker.cgi?action=view&key=13

Comment: @AdamLiter, thanks for filling me in on the context of the follow-up question. I did try using `\defglsentryfmt` but I couldn't manage to get the OP's error resolved using that (I also hadn't worked with `glossaries` until this issue came up for me). I agree that it is really a `leipzig` bug that should be fixed by Natalie -- thanks for contacting her.

Comment: @egreg, I'm puzzled as to why this fix doesn't work within `\renewcommand...` in the `.tex` file. But given that I didn't suggest doing that, is it really fair to say the answer doesn't work as advertised? I'm not claiming this is the best solution, but I identified the source of the problem (the deprecated commands) and provided a solution that resolves the problem, even if it can't be extended to work in the `.tex` file.

Comment: Changing a package file is something like a deadly sin, not just for licensing issues. Can you please change the answer and suggest to make changes to a *copy* with a *distinct name*?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I have now edited the answer to make it more explicit that users should change a copy of the style file and not the original.

Comment: Thank you. Did you know, that this answer is quite confusing for me? I was born in a little town called *Zeitz* which is about 50 km away from *Leipzig*. I always misread your name.

Answer (score 3):

At least as of the June 16, 2017 release of `leipzig`, this no longer seems to be a problem. You just need to use the `glosses` package option. (This is explained in the “Multiple glossaries” section of the documentation.)

```
\usepackage[glosses]{leipzig}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `leipzig.sty` is the correct way to go.  There is a little confusion, however...
There are two locations where `leipzig.sty` appears (in Miktex on Windows 7, 8, 8.1):
1. `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\leipzig`
2. `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\leipzig`

When changing the first one, I had no success.  When changing the second one, recompiling my file got the workaround to function properly.  Thanks, @Jason Zentz!