# How to patch a command from leipzig.sty

Tags: glossaries, linguistics, patching, xpatch, leipzig

As shown in [Issues with leipzig and glossaries used together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204575/32888), there is a problem when using the package `leipzig` with the `glossaries` package since the `leipzig` package relies on deprecated commands from `glossaries`.

The answer to the question solves the issue, but the answer suggests modifying the `.sty` file, which I would rather not do.

I have tried to patch the `\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle` command, but I have not been successful. According to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/32888) to [Please tutor the usage of patchcmd and xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152773/32888), one should use `xpatch` when trying to patch a command with an optional argument. `\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle` is such a command, but trying to patch it with `\xpatchcmd` does not work for me. How can I fix the issue without resorting to (copying and) modifying the `.sty` file?

### MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\usepackage[nomain,nostyles]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}{%
    \defglsdisplay[#1]{\leipzigfont{##1}##4}%
    \defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{\firstleipzigfont{##1}##4}%
}{%
    \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\ex
\begingl
\gla mulle//
\glb \First\Sg:\Dat{}//
\endgl
\xe

go.\Pst{}

\printglossary[style=inline,type=\leipzigtype]

\end{document}
```

You can see that it still produces the problem noted in [Issues with leipzig and glossaries used together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204575/32888).

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm not getting that error I don't think? I just tried searching the `.log` file for that error and nothing comes up.

Comment: @AdamLiter: Your patch merely seems to attempt to redefine `\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle`. Why not just redefine it then rather than patching it? Also, do you want to redefine it to `..##1..` rather than `..#1..`?

Comment: @Werner That's a good point ... and probably the more sensible thing to do ... `:)` I can't seem to get that to work, either, though. `\renewcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}[1]{\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}}` doesn't work, which is why I ended up trying to patch it. I'm sort of curious why patching doesn't seem to work, but also, at this point, any solution would be fine. As for `#1` vs. `##1`, I'm honestly not sure what the difference is. Does this have something to do with `glossaries`? I was just trying to change it to the accepted solution in the linked question.

Comment: @AdamLiter You're not trying a patch, as the text you want to substitute is the whole replacement text of the macro. So, if this patch were successful, it wouldn't be different from doing `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @AdamLiter Sorry about that. Most probably some leftover auxiliary file I had on my machine.

Comment: leipzig 2.0 is now available on CTAN (2017-06-16), and it fixes this issue (among others). However, if you are still using leipzig 1.0/1.1, then you can hack this by using \glsunsetall in your preamble. The reason you see PSTpastpst is a combination of bugs, but mostly because leipzig thinks you want the full abbreviation printed, as if on first use. (It's printing the short form correctly in smallcaps, then printing the long and short forms without smallcaps). Using \glsunsetall unsets the first use flag that is used by glossaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do patches with `etoolbox` when the search text contains `##` (note that `xpatch` is built upon `etoolbox`).

Also, the requested patch is just equivalent to

```
\renewcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}%
}
```

so it's not clear why you're looking for a patch.

By the way, `xpatch` is not strictly needed for the particular purpose, as `\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle` is not defined with an optional argument.

If you insist in doing a patch,

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}
  {\defglsdisplay[#1]{\leipzigfont{##1}##4}%
   \defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{\firstleipzigfont{##1}##4}}
  {\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}}
  {}{}
```

does the job.

But if I subsequently add

```
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}}

\ifx\test\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle\message{EQUAL}\fi
```

I find `EQUAL` in the log file, so patching is indeed not necessary and a redefinition should be used.

---

Probably

Comment: Whether this will do the job connected with the interaction between `leipzig` and `glossaries` is beyond the scope of the question. The proposed patch doesn't seem to solve the problem to begin with.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\renewcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}[1]{%`, not `\renewcommand*{\SetLeipzigDisplayStyle}{%`? But anyway, you're right about the patch not seeming to solve the problem. What I really don't understand though, is why patching/`\renewcommanding`ing `\SetLipzigDisplayStyle` in the preamable doesn't solve the problem, but copying and modifying the definition in the `.sty` file does. Shouldn't they have the same behavior? I guess that's a new question, but I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Using your test in a `.tex` file that is using a modified version of `leipzig` also returns `EQUAL` in the `.log` file, but the behavior is different. I'm so confused.

Comment: @AdamLiter I fixed the source; but I don't find differences between the behaviors with `\regexpatchcmd` and `\renewcommand`

Comment: I also don't see any differences in behavior with `\regexpatchcmd` and `\renewcommand`, either, but if you copy and modify the `.sty` file itself so that `\SetLeipsigDisplayStyle` is defined as `\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\leipzigfont{#1}}%` inside the `.sty` file then the undesired behavior goes away, even though your conditional test returns `EQUAL` in the `.log` file in all three cases.

Comment: Do you have any idea why there would be such differences in behavior? I thought patching or renewing a command was as good as changing it in the `.sty` file. I intend to accept your answer at some point, but I was curious if you happened to have any insight. Or should I just ask a new question? And for what it's worth, I agree that the accepted answer to the other question probably isn't really the right solution. According to the `glossaries` manual, `\defglsentryfmt` replaced both `\defglsdisplay` and `\defglsdisplayfirst`. But this is the first time I've ever looked at `glossaries`.