# redefining existing abbreviations for leipzig.sty

Tags: glossaries, leipzig

For writing linguistics papers, I use leipzig.sty for making lists of abbreviations used in glosses. In its documentation, there is the section "4.3 Redefine existing abbreviations"; however, it's left blank. That is exactly what I'd like to do, to redefine existing abbreviations with something else (especially for papers written in a language other than English).

Instructions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Added below is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,nostyles]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\makeglossaries

\newleipzig{erg}{erg}{nokaku}

\begin{document}

test\footnote{\printglossary[style=inline]}

{\Erg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be more specific? What precisely is “left blank”?

Comment: @egreg hi egreg, nothing is written in the document in that section. What I'd like to do is, e.g. redefine 'erg' as something other than 'ergative', more precisely, as 'nokaku', which means ergative in Japanese. I'd like to be able to do that just for papers written in Japanese, and still be able to use the predefined standard Leipzig abbreviations.

Comment: Looking at `leipzig.sty`, `\newleipzig{erg}{nok}{nokaku}` (or whatever) should do.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. That works for abbreviations not yet defined, but it does not work for those that are predefined. The predefined ones are listed in leipzig.tex, I think, but I don't want to make changes to that file. So, I'm hoping that there is a way to redefine (or override the predefined ones) in the preamble.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code. It will make things easier. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I should have done that. I added a mwe. I use xelatex, but platex gives me the same error.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that one has to delve into `glossaries` internals, because `\newleipzig` executes `\newacronym` and so trying to redefine an abbreviations conflicts with the already existing entry.

Comment: That's too bad... but thank you for your help. I'll wait and see if someone else comes up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer you an `\undefleipzig` so you are able to reset an abbreviation with `\newleipzig`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,nostyles]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\newcommand{\undefleipzig}[1]{\csundef{glo@\glsdetoklabel{#1}@name}}

\undefleipzig{erg}
\newleipzig{erg}{erg}{nokaku}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

test

{\Erg}

\printglossary[style=inline]

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\newleipzig` does `\newacronym`, when `glossaries` is loaded. So when one tries to redefine an existing abbreviation, the protection mechanism of `glossaries` enters into action. With the `\undefleipzig` trick, this mechanism is disabled for the particular entry we want to kill.

A possible definition of `\renewleipzig` to supplement the existing `\newleipzig` could be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,nostyles]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{glossary-inline}
\usepackage{leipzig}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\renewleipzig}[2][]{%
  \if@leipzig@defined{#2}
    {%
     \renew@leipzig{#1}{#2}%
    }%
    {%
     \PackageError{leipzig}
       {Abbreviation `#2' undefined}
       {No `#2` abbreviation is defined, use \string\newleipzig}%
     \@gobbletwo
    }%
}
\def\if@leipzig@defined#1{%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\ifcsname\@car#1\@nil}\@cdr#1\@nil\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\def\renew@leipzig#1#2{%
  \ifcsname glo@\glsdetoklabel{#2}@name\endcsname
    \csundef{glo@\glsdetoklabel{#2}@name}
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\newleipzig{#2}}{\newleipzig[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\renewleipzig{erg}{erg}{nokaku}
\newleipzig{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}
\renewleipzig[first=UUU]{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

test

\Erg{}

\Aaa

\Aaa

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

I'm not sufficiently expert in `leipzig` to understand if the result is as expected.

Comment: Thank you @egreg! This works perfectly! I'm really thankful.

Comment: The second solution didn't work. It gave me: "bbb bbb ccc. 1
erg erg nokaku. 1".

Comment: Hi @renoh, I know this is an old thread, but this is a behaviour of leipzig that I haven't been able to pin down. It only happens on some systems, so it probably has to do with the particular version of glossaries which you have.

Try putting `\glsunsetall` after `\makeglossaries` and before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @egreg's answer was so nice that I included it in a package update (leipzig 2.0, added to CTAN 2017-06-16). The update also fixes some other bugs, including the "bbb bbb ccc." problem. (For that issue, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204575/issues-with-leipzig-and-glossaries-used-together) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230874/how-to-patch-a-command-from-leipzig-sty) question.

Comment: @NatalieWeber You're welcome!