# Leipzig and glossaries: compatibility problems, and glossary does not appear

Tags: glossaries, linguistics, leipzig

I am using the `leipzig` package, which provides shortcut macros for linguistic gloss abbreviations, and interfaces with the `glossaries` package to index these abbreviations. I am compiling properly (running `pdflatexmk`) throughout.

According to the [`leipzig` package documentation](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/leipzig/leipzig.pdf), `leipzig` automatically loads `glossaries`. So, according to the documentation (p. 2), MWE#1 should produce the following output (minus the weird spacing, for which see same page of the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
  Use at least one macro like
  {\Nom}.\footnote{\printglossaries}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is where my first problem arises: MWE#1 does not typeset on my system. Instead, I get an error message saying that `\makeglossaries` is an undefined control sequence. It seems that `leipzig` is not really including `glossaries` by default, which is strange.

I understand it's possible to invoke `glossaries` as an option on `leipzig`, so I modify the code as in MWE#2:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[glossaries]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
  Use at least one macro like
  {\Nom}.\footnote{\printglossaries}
\end{document}
```

Attempting to typeset this yields the following error message:

> Error: \acrpluralsuffix undefined.

This refers to a line in `leipzig.sty` (see package documentation p. 30):

> \renewcommand*{\acrpluralsuffix}{\glstextup{\glspluralsuffix}}%

So this may be a bug (?), but I cannot tell.

The last resort is to invoke `glossaries` separately from `leipzig`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
  Use at least one macro like
  {\Nom}.\footnote{\printglossaries}
\end{document}
```

MWE#3 seems to circumvent the earlier problem, in that now the code typesets with no error messages. But a new problem appears: the glossary does not appear at all. Although the abbreviation produced by `{\Nom}` typesets correctly, the footnote where the glossary is meant to be appears empty:

[image]

I am led to believe this is due to some fault with `leipzig` and not `glossaries`. One clue to this fact is that `makeglossaries` gives no output when I run it on MWE#3:

> Scanning input file MWE3.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
>   Nothing written in MWE3.gls.

Furthermore, if I define a normal abbreviation alongside one of the `leipzig` abbreviations, the glossary appears showing the former, but not the latter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},
sort=M,
description={mass},
symbol=kg}

\begin{document}

Here is a linguistic abbreviation, {\Nom}.

Here is a physics abbreviation, \gls{M}.

\footnote{\printglossaries}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, whenever I try to use the `leipzig` command `\makeglosses`, I get an `Undefined control sequence` error.

I am using a standard MacTeX distribution with the latest version of `leipzig` and a recent enough version of `glossaries`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a known bug. There may be a similar question already on the site.

Comment: @AlanMunn Indeed, I thought my problem might fall under the purview of this [1] question, but it seems the discussion there regarding modifying the style file isn't current as of the latest version of `leipzig`, and furthermore my first problem, whereby `leipzig` doesn't seem to invoke `glossaries` at all, seems quite separate from what is discussed elsewhere.


[1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204575/issues-with-leipzig-and-glossaries-used-together

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of glossaries properly (e.g. extracting files, running mktexlsr or texhash, etc.)? Same with leipzig?

Are you able to compile the minimal example included in the glossaries package?

I've never heard of this error, so it would be good to figure out.

Comment: @NatalieWeber I just re-installed both glossaries and leipzig, and the example minimal.gls compiles just fine, but the original problem persists. I wonder if this is a wider issue with my own distribution though - I'll reinstall MacTeX and see what happens.

Comment: @Lefteris_the_linguist All of these work fine on my system (TL 2018 MacTeX). I suspect you have a local copy of `leipzig` lurking around in your local `texmf` folder. Check the log file to see where the packages are being loaded from. They should be `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/leipzig/leipzig.sty` etc., not something local.