# leipzig package gives glossing abbreviations but does not print glossary

Tags: glossaries, linguistics, leipzig

I used `leipzig` when typesetting my paper to get glossing abbreviations in smallcaps more easily and to automatically generate a glossary. However, I didn't get the package to work as it did for others. The glossing macros worked fine, but the glossary didn't appear (I used `\footnote{\printglosses}` and only a blank footnote appeared).

Does anyone know what the cause of this error is?

I then toyed with the minimal example in the package documentation, and the result was the same. I tried with another device (though same distribution [MikTeX] and editor [TeXworks]), and the result was still the same--could this be due to the editor?

There was a similar question (well, practically the same problem) a few years back:

> [Leipzig and glossaries: compatibility problems, and glossary does not appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423247/leipzig-and-glossaries-compatibility-problems-and-glossary-does-not-appear)

where the author of the package also commented. But there hasn't been any development for some time and there's really no solution yet, so I reckon I should post a separate one.

Comment: Follow suggestions in the question comments. For me, TeXlive 2020, it works as expected (I have used MWE from the linked question) – there is a footnote generated with description of "NOM."

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem this week.

I am using the most recent versions of MacOS, MacTeX, TeXMaker, TeXLive/TeXLive Manager, and all my packages.

If you are on TeXMaker, go to User --> User Commands --> Edit User Commands then, after "menu item" type: Make Glossaries and after "command" type: makeglossaries % (the % here is important and refers to whatever file you are using).

Click "ok" and the screen should go away. The go to User --> User Commands --> Make Glossaries (click "Make Glossaries"). I do it twice just to be sure.

Then run everything like you normally would. For me, this was the trick that finally worked.

Note: you still need \makeglossaries in your preamble, I believe. You just *also* have to perform the steps above.

Remember to click "Make Glossaries" again if your running list of Abbreviations is not up-to-date.

Check out my similar recent question and the answers to it here: [UPDATED: {leipzig} Package [still] Not Producing a Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565857/updated-leipzig-package-still-not-producing-a-glossary)

Hope this helps! :)