# UPDATED: {leipzig} Package [still] Not Producing a Glossary

Tags: glossaries, texmaker, mactex, linguistics, leipzig

[update: I tried the answer (as best as I could) that was commented and seemed to work for one person, but the problem is still persisting]

I tried this on PDFLaTeX, but since asking this question I have *switched to XeLaTeX,* if that makes a difference. I have updated screenshots to reflect this, but note that I could not get it to work on PDFLaTeX, either.

I am new to using LaTeX for linguistics and only used it for math in the past. I am currently applying to grad programs in linguistics so I am using LaTeX for my writing sample. I feel like there has to be something easy that I am missing, but I have combed through all the other stackexchange threads I could find and various manuals online to no avail.

I ensured that I had both `{leipzig}` and `{glossaries}` downloaded:

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Here is a link to the Leipzig Package Documentation/Manual: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/leipzig/leipzig.pdf

Here is a screenshot of the minimal code listed for an inline glossary in the package documentation:

[image: Package Documentation Picture 1]

This is what the code for that looks like in my XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
    
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
    
\title{TitleTitleTitle}
    
\author{My name}
\date{October Blah, 2020}
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
    
Use at least one macro like {\Nom}. \footnote{\printglosses}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Code Screenshot 1]

I tried to use /usepackage[glossaries]{leipzig}, as well.
I also replaced /makeglosses with /makeglossaries -- no combo seems to work.

I compiled it with XeLaTeX at least two times every time.

I also tried adding \usepackage{glossaries} and \usepackage[inline]{glossaries} before \usepackage{leipzig} in the preamble.

Adding \usepackage{glossaries} (note that this is not in the package instructions code) gave me the following error:

[image: Error Pic 1]

Using \usepackage{glossary-inline} fixed this error; however, it still did not produce a glossary. I just had the following code, but still no change in the actual document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
    
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-inline}

\usepackage{leipzig}
    
\title{TitleTitleTitle}
    
\author{My name}
\date{October Blah, 2020}
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\maketitle
    
Use at least one macro like {\Nom}. \footnote{\printglosses}
    
\end{document}
```

I am using the latest versions of MacTeX, TeXMaker, Leipzig, and Glossaries and am running the last OSx.

There is a second suggested code in the Leipzig Package Documentation (and in fact, this type works better for my paper, but still does not work).

Here is the screenshot of the package documentation:

[image: Package Domumentation 2]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{asdf}

Use at least one macro like {\Nom}. \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Again, I tried both \makeglosses and \makeglossaries, as well as both the [block] and [mcolblock] options. None worked.

It results in this mess and still does not produce a glossary:

[image: Screenshot 99999]

I even added a \section{asdf} to see if it would print under it, but with no luck.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! I've been trying to fix this for literally weeks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation kind of buries the lede. The glossary itself is generated by the `makeglossaries` command. By default, TeXmaker doesn't provide access to it, but apparently it's not too difficult to add it. See this answer [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows)

From the terminal, the command sequence is:

```
pdftex foo
makeglossaries foo
pdftex foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I'm going to update the question quickly rn.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you actually ran the `makeglossaries` program at all. That's the key missing step. It's not a matter of putting `\makeglossaries` in the LaTeX file, there's a second distinct program that needs to be run.

Comment: Solved! Thank you so, so much :)